# Unable to receive the data (recv in cpp) put into socket(write() in java)

Tags: c#, java, android

I'm new to socket programming so as to test some cases I'm using a java side client to send integer data through socket and I want ot receive that data on the server side in cpp.

My code on client side (java) looks like

```
out=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
ar=1;
le=1;
out.writeInt(ar);
out.flush(); 
out.writeInt(le);
out.flush();
```

and im using recv function in cpp to receive this data. the code on cpp side looks like

```
  if (int(recv(acceptFD, &number, sizeof(int), 0)) != sizeof(int))
  {
     ALOGE ("error reading on socket: number of Args: %d,reutrned value =%d\n",number);
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) 
  {
    int len;
    if (recv(acceptFD, &len, sizeof(int), 0) != sizeof(int)) 
    {
        ALOGE ("error reading on socket: Len of Args: expected length :%d\n",len); 
         freeDebugCallbackArgs(i, args);
        return;
    }
```

and its showing the log as

> E/RILC    (  235): error reading on socket: number of Args: 16777216, returned value =-1073741824
>   E/RILC    (  235): error reading on socket: Len of Args: expected length :1075093557

It would be a great help if someone posts an answer to this. 
Thank you

Comment: Please show how you declare number. Also, what is the return value of recv?

Comment: number is declared integer. returned value =-1073741824 is the returned value from recv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stongly suspect this is a problem with the byte order.

The number 16777206 represented as hex is 0x01000000, which is 1677206 in little-endian representation, but 1 in big-endian representation.

Read your numbers as a byte array and include code to compensate for the different byte order between the Java source and C destination.

Comment: can u be more specific please. this little endian and big endian concept always bugs me. can u give me an example

Comment: Sure. Different computers record integers in different ways, the two most common ways being called big-endian and little-endian, and just to show how confusing it can be, I have it backwards in my answer. ;) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness To represent the number 1 you can use four bytes 00 00 00 01, with the least-significant byte last. You can also use four bytes 01 00 00 00, with the least-significant byte first. The two ends of your connection do not use the same byte order, so the numbers are coming out wrong.

Comment: ya tried converting the int to big endian it worked perfectly. thanks alot